# ALTER table query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I am trying to change the data type of one column in the table from biginteger to varchar.

```
myproject-# \d+ product_awbstock
                         Table "public.product_awbstock"
      Column       |           Type           | Modifiers | Storage | Description 
-------------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------
 airwaybill_number | bigint                   | not null  | plain   | 
 used              | boolean                  | not null  | plain   | 
 created           | timestamp with time zone | not null  | plain   | 
 modified          | timestamp with time zone | not null  | plain   | 
Indexes:
    "product_awbstock_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (airwaybill_number)
    "product_awbstock_used" btree (used)
```

I am using this query, the error is also given.

```
alter table product_awbstock ALTER  COLUMN airwaybill_number TYPE varchar(15);
```

> ERROR:  foreign key constraint
>   "awbstock_id_refs_airwaybill_number_d438187b" cannot be implemented
>
> DETAIL:  Key columns "awbstock_id" and "airwaybill_number" are of
>   incompatible types: bigint and character varying.

Comment: The error message states that this column is referred from other table. You can not have a reference between columns with different types.

Comment: You should delete constrains between product_awbstock.airwaybill_number and ?.awbstock_id

Comment: You also have to alter that other table's column to varchar. But what's wrong with the current bigint data type?

Comment: @jarlh  need to updated that field as alpha-numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

1. drop primary key constraint on first table

`ALTER TABLE product_awbstock DROP CONSTRAINT product_awbstock_pkey;`

2. drop foreign key constraint on second table

`ALTER TABLE ??? DROP CONSTRAINT awbstock_id_refs_airwaybill_number_d438187b;`

3. alter column data types on both tables

`ALTER TABLE product_awbstock ALTER COLUMN airwaybill_number TYPE varchar(15);`

`ALTER TABLE ??? ALTER COLUMN airwaybill_id TYPE varchar(15);`

4. recreate previously removed constraints

`ALTER TABLE product_awbstock ADD CONSTRAINT product_awbstock_pkey PRIMARY KEY (airwaybill_number);`

`ALTER TABLE ??? ADD CONSTRAINT awbstock_id_refs_airwaybill_number_d438187b FOREIGN KEY (awbstock_id) REFERENCES product_awbstock (airwaybill_number);`